# I want to change Vue components with media Queries

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, single-page-application

In my App.vue I've set my template like this

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-view></router-view>
<app-footer ></app-footer>
```

`app-header` sets a header component to every other component of my project (so I don't have to repeat myself). `app-footer` does the same, but with a common footer for all of my components.

This works perfect with my Desktop web, but for Mobile I would like to change the header component to a `new-header.vue`component, and I would like to get rid of the Footer when using a mobile device so it doesn't use screenspace.

How can I achieve this?  I tried to use `app-footer {display: none;}` in a media query at App.Vue but its not working.

Comment: You can't do `app-footer {display: none;}`, but inside your AppFooter component there should be a `<template>` tag with a main `<div>` (or other block-level element). Give **that** div an ID and target it via the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to use CSS to hide.  The beauty of Vue is that in the case of mobile, the code will not even be generated at all.

Use a v-if directive, and add an `isMobile` property to your data, computed, store, etc.  Or call a method to get it.

```
<app-footer v-if='!isMobile'></app-footer>
```

For the header, there are 2 ways.  Using a `component` element with `v-bind:is` to `swap in the correct one`, or using `v-if` and `v-else`

```
<app-header v-if='!isMobile'></app-header>
<app-header-mobile v-else></app-header-mobile>
```

Here is the official link to the Vue `dynamic component` approach.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html.

It would look like this:

```
 <component v-bind:is="currentHeaderComponent"></component>
```

In this case, you would set `currentHeaderComponent` based on your conditions.

If you insist on CSS and media queries for the footer, set the component `id` or `class`, and that in your CSS

Component

```
<app-header id='app-header'></app-header>
<router-view></router-view>
<app-footer id='app-footer'></app-footer>
```

CSS

```
#app-footer {display: none;}
```

Comment: very helpful, thanks. Although I used CSS media queries, but planning on using the vue-y approach you handled.